# Disabling middle-click paste doesn't work

Tags: paste, gnome-tweaks

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I cannot disable the middle-click paste feature for some reason.
I've tried it both through the GNOME Tweaks tool and the command line, but to no avail, it just simply doesn't work, not even until restart. Anyone had a similar problem, or at least knows how to fix it?

Comment: Would you like the middle button to do something else? Or are you just trying to disable it completely? 

Comment: I would still like it to function as I use it a lot for auto-scroll features and such

Comment: @Filec, did you find a solution?

Comment: @IttayD sadly not

Comment: People need a solution to this annoying behavior.

Comment: Any workarounds / fixes ?

Comment: Looks like this has been an issue for 8+ years. it's not going to be fixed. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739819, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/-/issues/51,https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/-/issues/356